# Getting blank when run the ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4. I am getting blank page output when running my app and also it does not show any error at command line. If anybody have any idea about this please problem please share with me. Thank you.

[image: Blank page and no error]

Comment: Did you create a new application or you have already an application and just run it.

Comment: I have already an application and run it.

Comment: In same ruby and rails version, please share the console data by running the application and when you are on blank page.

Comment: My output:  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ah0W4ZIx-hk/U131on6VYkI/AAAAAAAAA6s/WSTBNAkyvgo/w822-h513-no/blank.jpg

Comment: As the link, i thing you don't have anything on your home page in static pages controller.

Comment: what you have inside the static_pages_controller home method and aslo inside home.html.erb

Comment: Content in my home page is: <html>
<body>
 <p>This is home page</p>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Even all the pages are giving same result. that is blank and no error.

Comment: in controller: def home
  end

Comment: The routes are going right way but you write something wrong in your html page, first remove the html and body tag because that are present in application.html.erb and try to write somthing in application.html.erb to check that it's working.

Comment: no. getting same result.

Comment: Try to add text inside the h1 tag and it will not work then there should may be something wrong inside ur application.

Comment: i tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: check in layout field `<%=yield%>` is there or not?

Comment: It is there. also i have a navbar and footer in the layout. But the html view for all the pages are blank

Answer (score 1):

From your log, it shows your server is loading `/home` - which routes to `static_pages/home`. This means your rails app is responding to your request, and likely means the problem lies in either your `static_pages controller`, or `home view`

You should have this code at least:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
Class StaticPages < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end

#app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
Hello World!
```

If you update with your controller, view & rendered HTML code - it will be very helpful!

Comment: Content in my home page is: <html> <body> <h1>This is home page</h1> </body> </html>  . in contoller: Class StaticPages < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end